# I cannot optimize my Laravel app due to the following error

Tags: php, laravel, terminal

In the terminal I typed: `php artisan optimize`. The result is the following error:

```
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Foundation\Console\RouteCacheCommand::buildRouteCacheFile() must be an instance of Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection, instance of Illuminate\Routing\CompiledRouteCollection given, called in /var/www/laravelFolder/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/RouteCacheCommand.php on line 66

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/RouteCacheCommand.php:103
     99▕      *
    100▕      * @param  \Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection  $routes
    101▕      * @return string
    102▕      */
  ➜ 103▕     protected function buildRouteCacheFile(RouteCollection $routes)
    104▕     {
    105▕         $stub = $this->files->get(__DIR__.'/stubs/routes.stub');
    106▕ 
    107▕         return str_replace('{{routes}}', var_export($routes->compile(), true), $stub);

      +14 vendor frames 
  15  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle()
```

I'm lost as to what I can do about this and I'm seeing no answers online.

Comment: Have you tried `php artisan optimize:clear` and later run  optimize?

Comment: @ManuelGlez I just tried it and it works. The app still doesn't recognize new routes added.

Comment: run `php artisan route:clear`  and `php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: Thank you but I did. I'm still getting "Route [carousel.index] not defined."

Comment: Is carousel.index  defined en your  routes/web.php file?

Comment: Yes it is. It works in the development environment but not in production.

Comment: https://www.codewall.co.uk/laravel-route-not-defined-checklist/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245677/discussion-between-keron-maurice-and-manuel-glez).